# Using Django to display different features of a template in different "pages" of the project

Tags: django, responsive-design, django-templates, django-views, media-queries

I am working on the front-end of a website and now I am focusing on its responsive side.

In the desktop design, I have four pages in total. Therefore, 4 main templates: page1.html (containing 3 features total), page2.html and so on. Hence, 4 top navbar items.

In the phone design, I replaced the top navbar by a bottom navbar containing the same navbar items plus two additional ones.

The additional items are features contained in page1.html.

In the desktop design, page1.html shows all the 3 features. 
In the phone design, there are three bottom navbar items for each feature.

Aiming to avoid having to create additional templates for those features, views and urls so the user does not "guess" the url (e.g. www.mywebsite.com/page1/feature... I would like to know if there is a way of showing each feature (of the same template) according to the active bottom navbar item.

So if all three features found in page1.html have an independent bottom navbar item, when I have click on the navbar item of feature 1, features 2 and 3 would be hidden and feature one would be the one displaying. If I click on the navbar item of feature 2, features 1 and 3 would now be hidden and only feature 2 would be displayed in the main section.

I am not very familiar with Django yet, so I'd really appreciate if you could provide an explanation with your suggestions and correct me in any term I might be using wrong. I essentially just need to know the technical terms of what I must research to help me solve my issue. Any examples would be of course deeply appreciated!!!

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: read more about Bootstrap, I don't think your problem with Django.

Comment: @YazanM.Al-Horani could you be more specific about what I should be seeing in Bootstrap?